# Is there a module for "mail routing" in Drupal 6?

Tags: emails

Is there a module, with D6 support, that allows one to "route" e-mails.

For example, by default, e-mails would be sent out by the regular mechanism, but for some e-mails, say based on their ID or destination domain, where tracking is interesting, they could instead be passed of to a third party service (such as MailChimp, ExactTarget, MailGun etc).

Answer (score 0):

You could try: https://drupal.org/project/reroute_email
While it's mainly designed to reroute all email to predefined addresses, e.g during development, you could use it as a starting point for similar functionality.

Comment: I've actually looked at that module, as a previous answerer wrote basically the same thing, but shortly afterwards removed the answer. Unfortunately, what it is doing, hook_mail_alter, isn't sufficient, as it allows no control over the actual sending process.

Comment: @Letharion if you need to control the sending process, you can abort the mail send and queue the email your own way, by setting `$message['send'] = FALSE;`

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that is not supported in D6.

Comment: My mistake, D6 requires the patch on https://drupal.org/node/800434 to cancel mail send

Comment: Thanks, that issue might actually be worthwhile for me to try to progress. However, even with the ability to "not send e-mails", the functionality that I'm actually after is still missing. :)